# Excel - If Statement, 3 Conditions

Tags: excel

`A   B   C   D`
1  320,421 421,641         541,321 
`2  3`
3

```
`=IF(B1>A1,3,IF(D1>B1,3,IF(then(B1>A1,D1>B1),5,0)))`
```

`If B is greater than A = value of 3`
If D is greater than b = value of 3
`If B is greater than A and D is greater than B = value of 5

`Need some help please.`
Can't seem to get the value to return 5

Answer (score 0):

Because B1 is greater than A1 the first part of the first `IF` statement is true so all the rest aren't evaluated.  Do the "and" test first and you won't have a problem.

```
=IF(AND(B1>A1, D1>B1),5,IF(B1>A1,3,IF(D1>B1,3,0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND(D1>B1,B1>A1),5,IF(OR(D1>B1,B1>A1),3,"A is greater than B and B is greater than D"))
```

You have to think through when none of your conditions are met. Like what if A > B and B > D.